# Is it possible to customize forms.Booleanfield corresponding "true" and "false" values?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django `Model`, with a **value** field that is a `models.CharField`.

The corresponding form is always generated through a `ModelForm`, yet following some custom logic, I sometime replace the default field associated to **value** with a `forms.BooleanField`.

Is there a way to decide the actual values that the `forms.BooleanField` will expect and return, instead of the default `True` and `False` ? (I would like to use the characters '1' and '0' in my model field).

---

To tell just a bit more about the reason for replacing the default `forms.Field`, in ascending order of importance:

- To present the user with a widget that is adapted to the expected input.
- To get the `forms.Field` validation.

Comment: Are you doing this because you want a checkbox widget? Because it'll probably be a better idea to change the widget of the CharField to a custom widget that meet your requirements.

Comment: @henrikstroem Thank you for your comment. The checkbox widget is indeed one of the reasons I want to do that. Yet the main reason is that I want the form to validate the fact that the provided "user input" is indeed a binary choice, and it was my understanding that the **validation** is actually the `forms.Field` business.

Comment: You'd be better off using a forms.ChoiceField, then.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for your suggestion. Why would it be better ? Just because it would be simpler to implement, or are there deeper rationale ? Also, would it be very complicated to change the "value interface" of a `BooleanField` ?

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel said, I think `forms.ChoiceField` is better. You already mentioned that it's a `models.CharField` in the model, but `forms.BooleanField` is designed to have only True/False values returned. On the other hand, `forms.ChoiceField` can accept any fixed choices and you can choose from multiple widgets to customize the display. Mostly I use the default `Select` or `RadioSelect`. Since you mentioned you want to use string "1" and "0" for this particular case, you can do:

```
blah_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('1', 'Yes'), ('0', 'No')))
```

or:

```
blah_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('1', 'Yes'), ('0', 'No')),
                               widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Also, if you really want to use checkbox, it's fine to use `forms.BooleanField` as well. Instead of doing any validation, which is not needed, you are responsible to write the code to convert `True` to `'1'`, `False` to `'0'` yourself, which is not complicated at all.

First, you need to make sure that your `Models.CharField` has `null=True` on it. In short, do the conversion in `views.py`, where you will save the form:

```
form = BlahForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    blah_field_value = form.cleaned_data['blah_field']
    blah_value = '1' if blah_field_value else '0'
    new_blah_obj = form.save(commit=False)
    new_blah_obj.blah_field = blah_value
    new_blah_obj.save()
```

If you are not sure that the code is doing, please look at [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#field-data).

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I like both directions you are describing. Could you please give some more pointers for the second approach " *write the code to convert True to '1', False to '0' yourself* " ? In particular, where should this code go ? (not the conversion code itself ; )

Comment: Please see my updated answer. On a second thought, it might not work, but please try and let me know and I'll modify the answer. The reason being: when you `save()`, django will try to save the data in `forms.BooleanField` into `models.CharField`, which I'm not sure if it will work.